# (Material-ui / React) Failed prop type: Invalid prop `cellHeight` supplied to `GridList`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

> warning.js:33 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `cellHeight` supplied to `GridList`.

I'm getting this error, yet the property worked. Is there anyway to get rid of this?

**Here is the documentation for Grid List from material-ui:**
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/grid-list

`cellHeight: 180(default)`

**The use in my code:**

```
<div className="images-tile">
  <GridList cols={4} cellHeight="120">
    {generateTiles(imagesArray)}
  </GridList>
</div>
```

**Visually (It works)**

[image]

**However getting this Error**

[image]

Comment: Maybe because you pass a string instead a number? `cellHeight={120}`

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in braces instead of quotes like the docs do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material UI's Gridlist component takes a number for the `cellHeight`

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div className="images-tile">
  <GridList cols={4} cellHeight={120}>
      {generateTiles(imagesArray)}
  </GridList>
</div>
```